# Existence and uniqueness of solution of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm working on a problem in Strauss' *Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction*. First, I'm asked to solve for the general solution of the second-order PDE $$3 u_y + u_{xy} =0 $$ with hint to use $v= u_y$. That part was straightforward, and I obtained the general solution $$u(x,y)= F(y)e^{-3x} + g(x) \text{,} $$ where $g$ is an arbitrary differentiable function of one variable and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}= f$ such that $u_y(x,y)= f(y)e^{-3x}$ for $f$ an arbitrary differentiable function of one variable.

The second part of the problem is that with auxiliary conditions $u(x,0)= e^{-3x}$ and $u_y(x,0)=0$, does a solution exist, and if so, is it unique? This is where I'm kind of stuck. Here's what I know so far:

1) $e^{-3x}= u(x,0)= F(0)e^{-3x}+ g(x) \implies (F(0)-1)e^{-3x}= g(x) \text{.}$
2) $0= u_y(x,0)= f(0)e^{-3x} \implies f(0)=0 \text{.}$
Correct me if I'm wrong, but would my second observation mean that $F(0)$ is a constant function of $y$ so that there exists a solution $$u(x,y)= Ce^{-3x}+ g(x) \text{,}$$ and since $C$ is completely arbitrary, then the solution is not unique? How should I proceed? I'm still having a hard time figuring out this part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[how to prove the uniqueness solution of the following PDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366996/how-to-prove-the-uniqueness-solution-of-the-following-pde)

Uniqueness is described here. Demonstrating uniqueness isn't that the solution is dependent upon a multiplicative constant, but rather no solution can be written that isn't described by the form you have found.